# What's the reason to use Singular Value Decomposition instead io $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ for pseudo inverse?

Tags: matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, pseudoinverse

I wonder what's the reason to use this formula from Singular Value Decomposition

$$
A = U\Sigma V 
$$
$$
A^{\dagger} =  V\Sigma^{-1}U^T
$$

Instead of 
$$
A^{\dagger} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T
$$

Both give the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $A$ isn't full-rank? Then $A^T A$ will be singular and its inverse will not exist. However, you can still do singular value decomposition and will see the $0$'s along the diagonal of the $\Sigma$ matrix. In some applications, it is okay to ignore the zeros and simply invert the non-zero entries of the $\Sigma$ matrix. Also, it is often the case that $A$ is close to being singular which can lead to numerical problems when you invert $A^TA$. This can be mitigated again by ignoring the really small eigen values in $\Sigma$ if appropriate.

Comment: So, SVD is much a better method to use?

Comment: Yes, but it's also more expensive. Also, matrix inversion is a more "basic" operation, much easier to understand and implement and much likely to be available in whatever environment/ language you're on.